# What is the best way of creating several rpm's (deb's) packages in one CMake project?

Tags: cmake, rpm, deb, cpack

I need to create several different rpm's (deb's) (with different list of files) from one CMake project.
What is the best way for this? Can some one suggest some project (CMakeList.txt) with such options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use CPack.

- [Packaging With CPack](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cpack/Packaging-With-CPack)